# CountIf() Function From VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013, worksheet-function

I am attempting to use the CountIf() function from my VBA syntax, but I get an error of

> Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

This is my syntax - what do I need to change so this is successful?

```
Dim countofemps As Integer

Sheets("All emps").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Allemps").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=filtervalue
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Allemps").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, _
    Criteria1:=">=1/29/2017", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=3/1/2017"
'This line throws error
countofemps = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("'All emps'!A2:A2000"), filtervalue, Range("'All emps'!B2:B2000"))
```

Comment: `Countif` takes two arguments. You might want to use `SumIf`.

Comment: But I do not want to sum the values, I only want a count of how many meet the criteria

Comment: Ok, but then why do you need the third argument?

Comment: I am needing to get a count of all values in column C where column A matches the variable `filtervalue`

Comment: @IcyPopTarts - Wouldn't that be the same as '*a count where column A matches the variable filtervalue*' ? If you want to exclude blanks in column C then use `WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("'All emps'!A2:A2000"), filtervalue, Range("'All emps'!C2:C2000"), "<>")`. Note countIFS, not countIF.

Comment: @Jeeped -> well yes, that is a more eloquent way of stating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go as follows:

```
With Sheets("All emps") '<--| reference your sheet
    With .ListObjects("Allemps").Range '<--| reference its "Allemps" table range
        .AutoFilter '<--| clear any previous filter
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=filtervalue '<--| filter referenced range on its first column with given filtervalue
        .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=">=1/29/2017", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=3/1/2017" '<--| filter reference range on its fifth column with given limit dates
        countofemps = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Columns(1)) -1  '<--| count the number of filtered cells on its first column except header cellr
    End With
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is `CountIfs`, with the criteria for the second argument column is "not empty":

Since you also want to filter the dates on `column 5`, you can integrate all your conditions in the countifs function (without the need for filtering), like this:

```
With Sheets("All emps").ListObjects("Allemps").DataBodyRange
    countofemps = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs( _
        .Columns(5),  ">=1/29/2017", _
        .Columns(5), "<=3/1/2017", _
        .Columns(1), filtervalue, _
        .Columns(3), "<>")
End With
```

Comment: That returns 0 everytime?

Comment: @IcyPopTarts not in my tests. Please check your data, you may have zero matches. Did I guess well what you want to achieve at least?

Comment: @IcyPopTarts just noticed, in your comment you want to exclude blanks in column `C`, but your OP code refrences column `C`. Tha's misleading. Try the edited code if it is column `C`.

Comment: This is counting all cells, not just the ones visible from my filter conditions.  (all cells where column A matches the variable `filtervalue`)

Comment: @A.S.H you need to add another Range and `Set` it only to that Range's `SpecialCells(...` , and then use that Range inside the `CountIfs`

Comment: @IcyPopTarts All your filtering conditions can be integrated in the `CountIfs`, as indicated in the edited version. @ShaiRado thx.